# Getting started with MySQL, need help structuring a database

Tags: mysql

Basically, I'm trying to make a database of collectible cards as a project to get familiar with MySQL and I'm unsure about how to approach setting this up.

Essentially, the database boils down to holding information about individual cards. For example a card will have:

- A Name
- Some text associated with the card
- Color

Also, these cards will belong to sets. A set is a group of cards released in that set. The only information stored about a set is:

- The name of the set
- The release date of the set

I was approaching this as a many-to-many relationship joined in a joiner table. Since one card can be in several sets and one set can contain multiple cards it made sense.

However, I have a couple problems with this setup.

The first is that information about the card can change with each set, but it is still the same card. For example, the text associated with the card may change but the card is still the same. Instead of having a new card for each set it is in, how would I go about reusing the information that will stay the same and only reflecting the change in text depending on the set? I was thinking about having another table of just card texts which would be linked in the same joiner table. Is this setup possible, and if it is, is it recommended?

Another problem I'm having trouble with is the issue of color. Every card will have a color, but the amount of colors a card may have can vary. For example, a card may be gold, white, and orange and another card may just be green. I would like for this database to allow searches for cards based on their color and for it to output a list of all cards of a color or combinations of color.

To do this, I was thinking that I would have a separate table for each color and implement this as a one-to-many relationship between the cards and colors. Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I sound like an idiot.

Comment: Nah you don't sound like a dummy- your secondary tables are possible and would be perfectly reasonable. You are the best suited person to answer most of these questions, give it a try with some test data!

Comment: You need two tables: `Card` for the features of a card that are independent of the set, and `CardInSet` that contains the set-specific features of each card. You could put this information in the relation table that's used for the many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track, but I don't like the idea of creating a separate table for each color. Instead, I recommend doing something like this:

Create a Card table with all of the information that stays the same about the card. Each row should have a unique card ID.

Create a Set table that contains information about the set. Each row should have a unique set ID.

Create a Color table that has a row for each color with each color having a unique color ID.

Create a CardText table that contains the text, the card ID, and the set ID.

Create a CardColor table where each row has a color ID, card ID and set ID.